# Make the screen to appear again when the screen is off by just touching the screen. Instead of pressing the on/off button

Tags: touchscreen, standby

Our system at work is automated. Sometimes a machine stop and we get the fault popping up on a android device everyone is carrying.
It's a Cat B15 Mobile with Android 4.1. 
We are carrying the phone with a holder around our arm.

If the screen is on all the time, the battery drains out pretty fast.
So I want to make the device to shut down the screen, and when I touch the screen it will start again.
Right now it's a little complicated to press the on and off button. Because the holder is blocking it.

Anyhow, if this was a possibility it would make everything a lot easier!
I checked the settings but didn't see anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no such facility (though it might exist a device which has this, I've not yet heard of). Screen off means screen off.

However, I may be able to offer an alternative: [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker) can react on "motion" as well, so you could use a "shake-pattern" as trigger. A profile I could imagine:

- **Condition:** Shake twice (record the shake-pattern)
- **Task:** Turn display on, unlock, bring app to foreground

I'm not sure if "shake patterns" could also be something like "tap the device twice", so you could try that as well. And though *Tasker* is a payed app (worth every cent!), there's a free, fully functional 7-day-trial available on their homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching the playstore. if you gave a proximity sensor on your devices try using that. Magnetic sensors use less battery, but you need a magnet to activate.Another option are g-sensors. The screen will not register touches while turned off (some very rare devices do).